# PyDev - Importing relative to project root name

Tags: pydev

Say I have a project named "abcproject". Is there any way to import like so in PyDev?

```
from abcproject.core.page import Page
from abcproject import util
```

As opposed to this, which works perfectly:

```
from core.page import Page
import util
```

If I add my project folder to my PYTHONPATH it will vaguely work, but PyDev will treat the imports as external and doesn't seem to update them properly as things change, which gets really messy.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely.

The problem is that you have to set as a source folder the folder containing the 'abcproject' and not the 'abcproject' itself.

I.e.:

You need a structure such as:

```
/my_project
    /abcproject
        __init__.py
        /core
```

And /my_project must be set as the source folder (in project properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > Source folders).